# Removing the Cell Gap between Jtable Columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am populating the jTable from DB but puts gap for each cell up to beginning of the next column shown in picture below , how to fix that ? I will be happy you can comment on this thanks.

[image]

Comment: Your problem here isn't the gap, it's the size of your table. That size is dictated by layout constraints that your question does not inform us on.

Comment: Unless you mean to say you want everything pushed tightly to the left with a big gap on the right? Be more clear.

Comment: So I must Resize the jTable ok thanks schmop

Comment: yes yes how to do that

Comment: What layout exactly you are using, placing code in question will get more reply..

Comment: free design layout , netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you must have a reference to your JTable

You can use something like this.

```
yourTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(10);
yourTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(20);
```